# User login, authentication, and sign up in Django 1.10

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having trouble distinguishing between logins and signups in Django. I was able to successfully create a signup form (that also logs the user in upon sign up.) I am struggling to make a separate sign in form.

The following code successfully renders a form with 'username' and 'password' fields. Upon clicking "submit" the info gets stored as the user object, then gets normalized, then gets saves to the database, and then is used to log in the user.

I tried to delete the user.save() line because I thought that would make the difference between *adding* a user and *logging in* a user. However, my terminal shows an unsuccessful post request ("POST /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1227) when this happens.

Please let me know what I can do to simply let the user sign in if his account info already exists in the database. Thanks!

```
class LoginFormView(View):
form_class = LoginForm
template_name = 'polls/login_form.html'

#display blank form using get
def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

#process the form data using post
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save(commit=False)

        #cleaned and normalized data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        #return user object if credentials are correct
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('polls:index')


    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation. What is `LoginForm`? What does its `save()` method do? If it's a login form, why are you setting the password? Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) including a login view. Why not use that instead of writing your own?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you already done the long process just, create another view to handle the login.

```
  class LoginView(generics.FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'polls/login_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=usernamem, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(user, self.request)
                return redirect('polls:index')
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```